# Set custom style inside ipywidget widgets elements

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to colorize the text in an `ipywidgets.widgets.SelectMultiple`.

I tried the following without success

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import widgets, interact

colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
prefix = lambda idx: r'\(\color{'+colors[idx%len(colors)]+'} {'
suffix = r'}\)'
d = {
    "option"+prefix(0)+"1"+suffix: 1,
    "option"+prefix(1)+"2"+suffix: 2,
    "option"+prefix(2)+"3"+suffix: 3
}
@interact(data=widgets.SelectMultiple(options=d, description="selector"))
def _(data):
    print(data)
```

Is it possible to set a custom style to a part of an ipywidgets widget ?
How can I make the text interpretable in order to resolve HTML?

Thanks